# Angular Material Table - how to place *ngIf on whole column?

Tags: html, angular, html-table, angular-material

I have an Angular Material Table and would like to place an ngIf on the whole column so the whole column, header & data cells only show if the condition is true. I can place it on the data cell with little issue but I can't seem to work how to place it on the ng-container or on the mat-header-cell.

I have tried using ngFor and then using an ngIf, I have tried wrapping the header in a div or a table header & row but no luck.

result is the object, which has a property of websiteUrl

```
<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource">
    
    <ng-container matColumnDef="websiteUrl">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Website Link</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let result">
            <div *ngIf="showWebsiteLink===1">
                <div *ngIf="websiteLinkVisible(result)">
                    <a (click)="copyLink(result.websiteUrl)">
                        Copy Link
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a very simple example for you. To remove the entire col you would need to use `*ngIf` to remove it from the template when `someCondition` is false. And also you would need to remove the same col name from `displayedColumns` array. The latter is more important. In the example I have removed col 'weight'.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  someCondition: boolean = false;
  
  constructor() {
    if (!this.someCondition) {
      this.displayedColumns.splice(2,1);
    }
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-kdttsz?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts